# Azure linked ARM templates passing parameters from file vs inline problem

Tags: azure, templates, deployment, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

We are working on **linked azure ARM templates** for our deployment.

The problem we are facing is if we choose to have different parameter files to link, like below, then we cannot use function in them.

```
linkedTemplateParameters.dev.json
linkedTemplateParameters.prod.json
linkedTemplateParameters.staging.json
```

for e.g. i can **NOT** do somethign like below in a parameter file

```
  "parameters": {
      "tenantId":  {
         "value": "[subscription().tenantId]"
      }
    }
```

so we have to hard-code them in the parameter files.

Now this might be bad in itself, but in cases where there is absolutely no way of giving a static value but need to dynamically fetch/generate it, that limits us to use parameter files altogether as we cannot mix passing parameters inline and via parameter files

**Is there a way to pass dynamic parameter values still keeping the parameter files?**

Comment: Try with "defaultValue" instead of "value", but I think that you need to use the variable object instead of parameters!! Try it!!